# Jumpy multitouch

Tags: macos, trackpad

After some random amount of time (and sleep-wake cycles) multitouch on my laptop became very *jumpy*. All multitouch actions start to perform only after I take away fingers after swipe. For example, both on external and internal trackpads scrolling became very hard when this bug appears because I need to replace single big swipe with many short ones.

System reboot or killing WindowsServer process (or just logout, not sure) normalize multitouch behaviour, but only for some amount of time.

Scrolling with other devices (like logitech mouse) works fine, so I think it's something with trackpad software.

Hardware:

- MacBook Pro 15" 2012 on Mavericks and Yosemite
- MacBook Pro 13" Retina 2014 on Yosemite

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I found it. I've started to stop every single non system process and after killing "[BetterSnapTool](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580)" utility multitouch normalized.